# Где лучше создавать слушателей?

Tags: java, gui

Я разбиваю свой класс GUI на несколько классов (один для создания `JTabbedPane`, другой для создания `JMenuBar` и т.д), а потом, в главном классе все это собираю вместе и получается GUI. Делаю я так для того, что бы соблюсти принцип единственной обязанности (*single responsibility principle*), и просто потому, что так действительно удобнее разбираться в коде.

Но у меня возникла проблема со слушателями моих пунктов меню(`JMenuItem`).

Например, есть пункт меню "сохранить" и по нажатию на него данные должны сохранятся в базе данных. Дело в том, что данные я получаю из текстовых полей(`JTextField`), которые находятся на панели, которая создается в главном классе GUI. Потом эти данные мне приходится передавать в класс меню(хотя они там абсолютно неуместно смотрятся) и уже в классе меню я создаю слушателя, который сохраняет их в базе.

Может быть лучше создавать этих слушателей в основном классе GUI? Тогда они смогли бы спокойно пользоваться всеми нужными данными из класса GUI. Можно было бы сделать методы для доступа к этим слушателям и меню пользовался бы этими методами.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте выделил бизнес логику(типа сохранения), вообще в отдельный сервис, который уже имеет доступ ко всем нужным классам и полям. И в листенере вызывал его метод.

Comment: @Vartlok, Спасибо! Но у меня так и сделано. Сохранение идет в отдельном классе. И листенер вызывает его метод. Но этот метод требует данные для сохранения в качестве параметра. Следовательно, листенер должен иметь доступ к этим данным. И если я засовываю его в меню, то получается что и в меню приходится передавать эти данные. В общем, все запутывается в какой то очень тугой клубок